# Game Of Life, FileIO Storing boards

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I've been working on this for the past 4 hours or so, and can't figure out what to do. I'm porting my Game of Life to C and cannot get the FileIO to work properly. The input file is in the format of:

```
Game 1: Pattern Name
10 20
// Pattern here
Game 2: Pattern Name
15 25
// Pattern here
```

So on and so forth until the end of the file. What I want to do is print the game, and create a multi-dimensional array of the size `10` and `20` for the first game, then store the pattern in this array. Here's what I have so far:

```
void fileIO() {
    FILE *file;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int rows = 0, cols = 0;

    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file.");
    } else {
            while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file) != NULL) {
                    if(strstr(buffer, "Game") != NULL) {
                            printf("%s", buffer);
                    } else {
                            sscanf(buffer, "%d%d", &rows, &cols);
                    }
            }
            fclose(file);
    }
}
```

And here's where I hit the wall, and run into a list of problems,

`Creating a dynamic global multi-dimensional array`

`Preventing the buffer from reading into the next game`

I figured that the best way to do this would be to create a struct array for each game like,

```
struct game {
    char board[][];
};

struct game games[];
```

However, I don't know how to dynamically set the parameters for the amount of rows and columns in each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a relatively new C programmer but I think I may be able to help with dynamic arrays. C initialises arrays during compile time which doesn't work if you need to set them dynamically. So rather than use notation like:

```
char board[][];
```

You need to use pointers and allocate them memory according to the required size of the array. This is done using the malloc function. For example:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int i;
char **board;
board = malloc(rows * sizeof board[0]);

for(i = 0; i<rows; i++){
board[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof board[0][0]);
```

If you haven't learned about pointers and memory allocation then I'm not sure if this will help you much. I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do so I can't give you a specific example of the code but this is a more general way of dynamically allocating arrays.  Like I said I'm a beginner with C so I apologise if that doesn't help. Here is a good link that will help with understanding pointers.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays